# Index in SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index

I have table with structure

- LocId **varchar**
- ParameterId **varchar**
- Mdate **datetime**
- pvalue **double**

With primary key on first three columns and clustered Index on same column.

1. I found when in where clause there is **LocId,parameterId,mdate** in
   query excecution plan it shows seek
2. I found when in where clause there is **LocId** in query excecution plan
   it shows seek
3. But where in where clause there is **ParameterId** in query excecution
   plan it shows scan.

Comment: `shows seed` or shows index scan?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft is correct.  If you frequently query with ParameterId alone, you may wish to consider creating an index on ParameterId.  However, keep in mind that more indexes means more time to write data for every row, so if the table is infrequently queried this way but frequently modified, it may not be worthwhile.

Comment: @andrews Sorry it is index scan